# CodenameOne WebBrowser Google maps issue

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I am working on a simple prototype that takes location co-ordinates and call a page on my server that shows the map with the co-ordinates as the centre point. The page on the server works perfectly fine.
Now I called this page via the WebBrowser component of CN1. It display perfectly fine on the emulator (screen shot attached).
However, it shows a blank screen on the device. I am trying on a Samsung Galaxy Note.

[image]

Device:

[image]

The code:

> ```
> protected void beforeMapFrom(Form f) {
>     super.beforeMapFrom(f); 
>     if (loc != null) {
>         findCords().setText("Lat:" + loc.getLatitude() + "::lng:" + loc.getLongitude());
>         WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser() {
>             @Override
>             public void onLoad(String url) {
>                 findLoaded().setText("Loaded");
>             }
>         };
>         f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, web);
>         web.setURL("http://ipaddr/Maps/index.jsp?lat=" + loc.getLatitude() + "&lng=" + loc.getLongitude());
>     }
> }
> ```

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: I even tried to load https://www.google.com. Its still a blank screen on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If it possible you have something else within the GUI builder that you aren't removing?

Do you have something in the `postMain(Form)` method?

Technically the `findCords()` method you are using shouldn't work you need to use `findCords(f)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The GUI builder has just two labels, one in north and the other in south. I am adding the Web browser component in the center. I have not over-ridden the postMain or even postMapForm. Have changed findCords() to findCords(f). Still the same

Comment: I did one change and it started working...Removed the checkbox for absolute center in the border layout of the form. So does this mean that we should bot have the Web Browser component at the absolute center ?

Comment: No. Absolute center gives the component its preferred size which on the device is 0 during initialization since the data hasn't arrived yet. It makes no sense for this case.

Comment: Well in that case, I even tried doing a revalidate, replaint once the page was loaded in the onLoad() method for the WebBrowser component. It still showed blank.